# Is there a limit on number of fields imported in QGIS? If yes, how to disable it?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, csv

I'm working on a dataset with around 200 fields. However, when I import the data (in the form of `.csv` file) as a layer, the attribute table does not display all the fields – around 100. Is there a limit on the number of fields that can be imported in QGIS? More essentially, how do I remove this limit (or set it to a comfortably high number) using python?

Answer (score 1):

The only concrete limitations on .csv files in general I could find was 255 columns/fields, but even this limit has become antiquated as advances in handling memory have greatly improved over time.

Looking closely at the QGIS documentation I did come across the CSVT file format which leads me to question how you are importing the .csv file? If you are using the *Add Delimited Text File* from the *Layer* menu, then you should see listed all the data (rows and columns) you are about to import.

Additionally and back to why I bring up the CSVT file format, are you certain that all of your fields are valid?

**From the QGIS Documentation:**

> If you have any data that is not a string (text) and the file is a CSV file, you must have a CSVT file (see section CSVT Files).

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fi/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#csvt-files

One last thing to consider is how your data is delimited; are you certain that none of your fields are unintentionally being merged with others?

*Note that my asking questions are rhetorical in nature and are meant to promote critical thinking towards solving the problem*